# How can I copy to the system clipboard from byobu?

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, byobu

How can I copy to the x system clipboard from byobu?

I know how to copy and paste within byobu (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/byobu.1.html)
and I can easily paste from the system clipboard into byobu with the expected ctrl+shift+V

I would ideally like to be able to highlight with the mouse or in byobu scroll mode and then ctrl+shift+c and/or right-click-> copy
If that is not going to be possible, integration of the internal byobu clipboard with the system clipboard would be grand.
Or any other solutions folk might use / have in mind? Surely this is a common task? I frequently want to copy from the terminal and paste into the browser, for example.

The only two solutions I have seen are:

1) An outrageous hack involving many keystrokes: https://dodoincfedora.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/integrating-byobuscreens-copy-buffer-with-xgnome-clipboard/

2) Selecting and copying to the internal buffer followed by:
echo [alt][insert] | xclip -selection c

How can I do this (surely very common?) task with less than a dozen keystrokes every time? :)

Comment: Answered on AskUbuntu - [How to copy command console text?](//askubuntu.com/q/37455)

Comment: Yes, I've seen this - there isn't a working solution there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + mark text with the mouse
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right click -> copy

Comment: thanks, yes, that does it. Also need to do shift+F11 to zoom in to just that panel.

Comment: I have dificulties to use this method when the test spans more than one page. The selection often disappers after some slight movenent.